# What are the Synthesis Tools supporting SystemVerilog 2012?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to compile and synthesis a design wrote with sv2012 , I was able to use vivado2014.1 to compile fine but i got a problem in synthesis since as per Xilinx Vivado doesn't support hierarchical  instances:
http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Synth-8-146-cannot-resolve-hierarchical-name/td-p/370713

I tried tools like precision and ISE but they don't support sv2012.

What are the Synthesis Tools supporting SystemVerilog 2012?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any synthesis tool that supports hierarchical references. It has nothing to do with SystemVerilog support. Synthesis tools want all signals to go through ports.

Comment: Agreed. Hierarchical referencing is for test-bench. The SystemVerilog (and Verilog) language is for design and verification. If hierarchical referencing was synthesizable, there would be no point to have input/output/interface ports.